# c++ Load bitmap from memory - memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, bitmap, gdi+

I have function, which creates `Gdiplus::Bitmap`.

```
Bitmap *LoadBitmapT(const unsigned char* fileBuffer, size_t length) {
   HGLOBAL m_hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, length);
   BYTE* pmem = (BYTE*)GlobalLock(m_hMem);
   memcpy(pmem, fileBuffer, length);

   IStream* pstm;
   CreateStreamOnHGlobal(m_hMem, FALSE, &pstm);

   Gdiplus::Bitmap *bitmap = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromStream(pstm, FALSE);

   GlobalUnlock(m_hMem);
   pstm->Release();
   return bitmap;
}
```

As you can see, memory leak appears thanks to `GlobalAlloc()`.

When I try to use `GlobalFree(m_hmem)` it solves my problem and memory leak disappear. But I am drawing obtained bitmap in another function with this code:

```
Graphics graphics(hdc);
graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, ....);
```

and when I don't use `GlobalFree()`, painted image is correct. But when I use mentioned function, than I lose correct image and it is image like blue screen.

Than I try to save pointer of `m_hMem` and call `GlobalFree()` after drawing bitmap. So, this is OK. But I need to use rotation on obtained bitmap, so when I call `bitMap->RotateFlip(RotateNoneFlipX);` than memory leaks appears again. Changing some color of pixel manually in bitmap makes same behaviour.

So, how can I release memory for this image and draw correctly this image. I need it, because I am drawing periodically a lot of images and so this allocates a lot of memory and then my program crash.

**Edit**

I tried this code:

```
Bitmap *LoadBitmapT(const unsigned char* fileBuffer, size_t length) {
    HGLOBAL m_hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, length);
    BYTE* pmem = (BYTE*)GlobalLock(m_hMem);
    memcpy(pmem, fileBuffer, length);

    IStream* pstm;
    CreateStreamOnHGlobal(m_hMem, FALSE, &pstm);

    Gdiplus::Bitmap *bitmap = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromStream(pstm, FALSE);
    GlobalUnlock(m_hMem);
    pstm->Release();

    GlobalFree(m_hMem);

    return NULL;
}
```

After this when I am looking on task manager, than I see that memory don't increase.

When I give `bitmap->RotateFlip(RotateNoneFlipX);`after `Gdiplus::Bitmap *bitmap = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromStream(pstm, FALSE);` and code is same but only this one line is added, than memory is increasing.

Comment: *So, how can I release memory for this image and draw correctly this image*  --  Copy the image data somewhere else, maybe on disk?  Otherwise, deleting the memory means deleting the data.  There is no way you can work on data that you've deleted.  Usually, the last entity to use the bitmap is the one that knows when it's really time to delete the data, thus you shouldn't be deleting the data like that.

Comment: I can't write it into the disk. I can have use case like: Load it from memory, draw it with graphics.drawImage and then when I want to paint another image than I can delete old from memory and so don't have memory leak. This works for me but if I call `bitMap->RotateFlip(RotateNoneFlipX);` or something like that, than I don't know why when call `GlobalFree` than nothing is deallocated.

Comment: Redesign your application to know who, where, and when is the *actual* time to safely delete the memory.  It seems you didn't think it through, to be honest.

Comment: This can helps me after that I can use GlobalFree after using method `bitMap->RotateFlip(RotateNoneFlipX);`. As I told, after this method when I try to use GlobalFree(), than nothing happens. When I don't use this function, than the memory clears.

Comment: How can you call `GlobalFree` outside of this function when the handle you have declared (`m_hMem`) is local to the `LoadBitmapT` function?  Did you call `GlobalHandle` to retrieve this value?

Comment: I've just edited question on top and give Edit, where is example how can I try it.

Answer (score 2):

I found answer.

This code deallocates everything correct.

```
HGLOBAL m_hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, length);
 BYTE* pmem = (BYTE*)GlobalLock(m_hMem);
 memcpy(pmem, fileBuffer, length);

 IStream* pstm;
 CreateStreamOnHGlobal(m_hMem, FALSE, &pstm);

 Gdiplus::Bitmap *bitmap = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromStream(pstm, FALSE);
 pstm->Release();

 GlobalUnlock(m_hMem);

 bitmap->RotateFlip(RotateNoneFlipX);

 delete bitmap;
 GlobalFree(m_hMem);
```

Need to call in correct order. So first delete bitmap and then GlobalFree